# Move 3D cursor back to center hotkey?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a hotkey to move the *3D Cursor* back to X=0 Y=0 Z=0?

[image]

Comment: Re: duplicate mark,  "Precisely move 3D cursor" asks about moving cursor to any spot in 3D space. The above question asks about a hotkey for re-centering the cursor. These are separate questions with different answers.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and then *"Cursor to center"*.

Or you can use use a direct hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

You can also use the right panel to set the position manually (bottom right of the picture) :
[image]

Comment: Isn't Shift  + C faster ?

Comment: Oh yes, i did not know this one. Thanks R00t !

Comment: But Shift + C changes the camera position, that's not always good

Comment: For anyone wondering this works in 2.8, too. I googled for this and this is the top hit.

Comment: in 2.8 it's called `Cursor to World Origin` for the `Shift + S` option

Comment: The camera change is indeed really annoying.

Answer (score 15):

To move the *3D Cursor* back to X=0 Y=0 Z=0 you may use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

File --> User Preferences --> Input -->

Name for 3d View command is 'Snap Cursor to Center'.

[image]

There in it can be changed to what ever.

Mine is set to 'P' since I don't use the Game Engine.